# Liferay bundled with JBoss 7.1.1 : Works only with JavaSE-1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, liferay

I've got Liferay 6.1.1 bundled with JBoss 7.1.1 Final. I've manage to configure it in Eclipse Luna, set JBoss server and now after typing localhost:8080 in my browser I can see Liferay welcome page.

The problem is that server only starts when its Runtime JRE is set to Java SE-1.6. When I change it to 1.7 or 1.8 server is starting, in console I can see a line

*JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final 'Brontes' Starting*

but that's it, nothing happens afterwards and server's state is 'starting' instead of started.

Anyone knows the reason why or knows how to fix it ?

I've got Java 8 and 7 installed, environment path is set to JDK7.

Comment: Did you verify JAVA_HOME enviroment variable? this variable have to point to the new folder JRE or JKD

Comment: Heh, problem solved, of course pretty simple : Eclipse hasn't seen my JRE7. JBoss -> Runtime Environment -> Insalled JREs... - > Add ->Standard VM -> ..